# Confused about prototype in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
var y=function(){
    return new y.prototype.greeting();
}
y.prototype={
    greeting:function(){
        alert("hello world");
    }
}

new y();
```

the above code will alert("hello world");

but if I remove the `.prototype` and change that line to `return new y.greeting();`

an error will be occurred:

> undefined is not a function

```
var y=function(){
    return new y.greeting();
}
y.prototype={
    greeting:function(){
        alert("hello world");
    }
}

new y();
```

why I can't  call the `greeting` method without `prototype` here?

thanks a lot

Comment: Perhaps you should include a full sample of your "prototype-less" code, rather than just saying which bits you have removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`y` is a function, the `[[Prototype]]` of which is `Function` - so when you ask the interpreter to look up `y.greeting` for you, it first looks at `y` itself, then it checks `Function.prototype` and then it checks `Object.prototype`.

When you *create* a `new y` then the `prototype` property of `y` will be set on the object that is created.  So if you did `new (new y()).greetings()` then you would get your `alert`.

Another way to think about it is the `prototype` property of a constructor function is the `prototype` of any child objects that will be created by calling `new constructor`.  The actual internal `[[Prototype]]` of the constructor will always be based on whatever constructed *it*.

You can see this in the example I put together below.  `Object.getPrototypeOf` will return the internal `[[Prototype]]` property, so we can see what is actually going on:

```
> var test = function() {}
> Object.getPrototypeOf(test)
function Empty() {}

// Setting the prototype property
// does not change the [[Prototype]] of test
> test.prototype = {x: 1}
> Object.getPrototypeOf(test)
function Empty() {}

// But it *does* change the prototype of
// objects *created by* test.
> var x = new test
> Object.getPrototypeOf(x)
Object {x: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

`return new y.greeting();` tries to access an attribute (function) of y which doesn't really exist. That's why it throws the error 'undefined is not a function' because, the attribute of y contains a variable which contains a function. It's like three floors, where you cannot go to ground floor from the second floor without going to first floor; kind of hierarchy. Got it?